# connection error of django with mongodb -

Tags: django, mongodb

I want to connect my django application with mongodb(mongoengine) and sql .
and i am using django1.8 and mongoengine.
I am getting this error-

command prompt-

```
(orahienv) somya@somya-Inspiron-15-3555:/var/www/html/admin_python$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/admin_python/settings.py", line 117, in <module>
    mongoengine.connect("mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017/pom")
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/connection.py", line 257, in connect
    return get_connection(alias)
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/connection.py", line 215, in get_connection
    'Cannot connect to database %s :\n%s' % (alias, e))
mongoengine.connection.MongoEngineConnectionError: Cannot connect to database default :
[Errno 111] Connection refused
```

setting.py-

```
import mongoengine
    mongoengine.connect("mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017/pom")
    DBNAME = 'pom'

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'pom',
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': 'root',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
        },

    }
```

Comment: The engine for shure is incorrect try: 'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',  (http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/django_python_mongodb_engine_mongo)

Comment: django version 1.8 does not support django_mongodb_engine

Answer (score 0):

## in settings.py

```
from mongoengine import connect

connect('your data base in mongo', 'an alias name expect *default*', host='localhost', port=27017)
```

## models.py

```
from mongoengine import DynamicDocument, IntField, DateTimeField
class PostData(DynamicDocument):
    created_time = DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    inventory_id = IntField(required=True)
    meta = {"db_alias": alias name, 'collection': 'post'}
```

## run in shell

```
import PostData

PostData.objects.create(inventory_id=34)
```

hope to work for you

- create your database in mongoDB beforehand